# Docx4j Class Not Found Error

Tags: java, netbeans, docx4j

I am trying to run a tutorial from [here](http://blog.iprofs.nl/2012/09/06/creating-word-documents-with-docx4j//.com)  Office Open XML. I have downloaded the Docx4j library and added it to the netbeans as a library.

the code snippet is given below

```
  import org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException;
  import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;


 public class OfficeOpen {


     public static void main(String[] args) throws Docx4JException {

        WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addParagraphOfText("Hello Word!");
        wordMLPackage.save(new java.io.File("src/main/files/HelloWord1.docx")); 
          }

  }
```

when I run the above example I get the following error

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.Base.<clinit>(Base.java:43)
at officeopen.OfficeOpen.main(OfficeOpen.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 2 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

looks like the JVM cannot find a class at run time, any suggestion.  I am using Netbeans 8.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing some libraries that docx4j depends on. See http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docs/Docx4j_GettingStarted.html at **docx4j dependencies**.

Indeed you are missing **slf4j** that docx4j uses for for logging: http://www.docx4java.org/docx4j/docx4j-3_2_0/dependencies/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar

Possibly you'll need many others.

I think this are all the dependencies, althought you may not need all of them: http://www.docx4java.org/docx4j/docx4j-3_2_0/dependencies/

Comment: The last link is dead now unfortunately